# style.css doesn't work on preview of webhoster for my website but it works in local "offline" HTML-file

Tags: html, css, web, web-hosting

I'm currently working on my own website. So i coded some HTML with a style.css . Testing it offline - everything works as expected but when I upload it to my webhoster and get a preview of my website, there is only the raw html visible without anything from the style.css

I already checked the path and overwrote it with the for me correct path (from the root of the webserver) - it changed a little bit but still is far away from the right appearance.

The head of my **index.html** (The only page I have)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title> test </title>
<link rel="icon" href="img/fav.png" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- main css -->
<link href="httpdocs/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- modernizr -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

as well as my path:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zAHe.png

The result is a described aboth only some html text but not how it would looks like with style.css

Comment: `href="httpdocs/css/style.css"` is probably incorrect. Try `href="/css/style.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use relative paths from the `httpdocs`.

So change `httpdocs/css/style.css` to `./css/style.css`.